# Animated TV show about guy with metal arm hunting monsters

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

When I was younger I watched an animated Series on Cartoon Network about a young blonde man, killing off biohazard monsters. Memorably, he had a metal arm.

Comment: Alienators had a blond guy helping to catch monsters. No metal arm though, if I recall correctly

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: The description partly matches [Generator Rex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_Rex), but the main character wasn't blonde. He did have "nanites" that among other things could turn his arms into giant metal ones. He also went around hunting monsters named EVOs along with a chimp sidekick.

Comment: [BraveStarr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BraveStarr) had a metal-armed hero fighting monsters and general villainy

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullmetal_Alchemist:_Brotherhood and its precursor series aired on Cartoon Network's Adult Swim block and as part of AS's revived Toonami block from 2010 to 2014. The main character is blonde and has a mechanical ("automail") arm and a number of episodes have him fighting magically-bioengineered monsters. Could be that.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 Add as an answer?

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 Please don't answer in comments.  If you have an answer, then write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

***Possible answer; links contain plot-related spoilers. Click at your own risk.***

You may be looking for the anime series *Fullmetal Alchemist* or *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood*.

*[Fullmetal Alchemist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullmetal_Alchemist_(TV_series))* is the first of the two adaptations of the manga series, which aired on Cartoon Network (via the Adult Swim block) from 2004 to **(can somebody find out when it stopped airing?)**. It was followed by a more faithful adaptation, *[Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullmetal_Alchemist:_Brotherhood)*, which aired on CN's Adult Swim block from 2010 to 2011 and then on its revived Toonami block from 2012 through 2014.

The main character, [Edward Elric](https://fma.fandom.com/wiki/Edward_Elric) is a young (~15 years old, younger in flashbacks) blonde man, with two robotic prosthetics (known as "automail" in the FMA universe): His entire right arm and his left leg from the knee down.

Ed using his alchemy/magic to modify his robotic arm into a swordlike weapon:

[image]

Throughout both renditions of the series, Edward and other characters fight alchemically-bioengineered monsters called [Homunculi](https://fma.fandom.com/wiki/Homunculus), most of which are physically based off representations of and/or named after the Seven Deadly Sins (Pride, Envy, Lust, Greed, Gluttony, and Wrath). Other alchemically-created monsters include [chimeras](https://fma.fandom.com/wiki/Chimera), combinations of two or more animals more-or-less gene-spliced together with magic.